# Run PHP task in the background on IIS

Tags: php, post, iis, iis-7, phpmailer

**Script:** Sending emails
**Using:** PHPMailer
**Process:**

- Submit PHP form
- Send email using PHPMailer and wait for transaction ID back from the sending server
- Insert the transaction ID and log the email in the database

This is all working fine, the only issue is if I have let's say 10, 20 or more emails to send, if each email takes 3-5 seconds to be send while waiting to receive the transaction ID back before continuing the loop then 10 emails are taking close to 1 minute and so on..

I was wondering if there is a way to submit the PHP form using POST the server somehow does its sending job and takes whatever time it needs in the background while the user can continue using the site or even close the page

Thank you

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a `cron job`.

Comment: Or `Task Scheduler`..

Comment: I thought of this but I wanted to see if there is any other option before I create a task scheduler. Thank you

Comment: A scheduled task is indeed the way to go, but you can speed up your sending substantially by basing your code on [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps), and by reading the docs on sending to lists in the PHPMailer project wiki.